# Excel Conditional Format: Highlight duplicate values in a column based on the contents of another cell (same row different column)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a dropdown box in column A.  Lets say I'm working row 10.  I select "Highlight" in cell A10.  When I do that, I would like a conditional format that highlights any cells in column B that match cell B10.  How can I do that?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this along the lines of what you're trying to do? https://exceljet.net/formula/highlight-cells-that-equal

Comment: @user2800 - It looks like it, except OP has a problem: There will be a circular reference.  If you're trying to look in column B for cells that contain the text that a specific cell in that column has, I can't think of a way to write a formula without it being a circular reference.

Comment: @BruceWayne I agree. One option may be to add a helper column C that checks the adjacent cell in Column B for a match to B10. Something like `=IF($C2=$B$10, TRUE, FALSE)`, and dragging down. Then the conditional formatting becomes fairly straightforward.

Comment: @user2800- Great idea, a helper column would make this much simpler and avoid VBA.

Comment: So maybe I'm missing something, but conditional formating with the following formula: `=AND(B1=B$10,$A$10="Highlight")` applied to column `B` worked fine for me. Problem is, you need a condition for every row in column `A` that has a dropdown, which may be a lot...

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I think a helper column would be great, but I would need it to identify other cells in column B that match B10, but only because A10 is "Highlight".  I don't know how to write a formula that identifies the column B entries for rows where A is highlighted.

Comment: Just to give you context, the spreadsheet is for organizing events.  When I'm acting on a responsibility related to that event, I have a column with the organizer's name.  Organizers often host more than one event and it would save a ton of time if I could quickly scan the sheet for duplicates of only a highlighted row's organizer and not all duplicates in the column, so that I could kill two birds with one stone and combine multiple conversations into one.  Filtering isn't an option.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, but it ended up requiring a number of helper columns.  Thanks for the suggestion, @user2800.  It worked and I posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select `entire B Column`.
- *Apply this Formula as `New Rule` & an appropriate `Color` to the column `B`:*

  ```
  =AND($B1=$B$10,$A$10="Highlight")
  ```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thanks for the suggestion.  I'm just wondering what is the significance of B1?  How does it figure into the formula?  Do I need to create a reference cell?

Comment: You can find the Numbers in Column B to highlight so as abandon precaution  better start with First Cell `B1` and you need to change it according to the Column `$C1` for Column C. ☺

Comment: @BrianH, significance of `$B1` is very simple the `Conditional format Formula` will check `Entire column B` starts from Cell `B1`. if you put `100` in `B1` will be Highlighted !!

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  Unfortunately it didn't work.  But with the help of a number of helper columns I was able to figure it out.  But thanks again for all your help.  I think the problem with this solution might relate to the requirement that there be a highlight.  I think this prevents the formula from finding the duplicates that don't have a highlight in their respective column A cells.

Comment: @BrainH,,, I'm surprised,,, the attached screen shot simply shown that conditional format highlights numbers in column `B` if are `100` & `A10` is `Highlight`.  **Could you edit your Post & include the Screen Shot !!**

Comment: Hi Rajesh.  I can't because it's a spreadsheet with sensitive info, but in your formula both $B$10 and $A$10 are static references.  In my spreadsheet, the row I'm working will be labled "Highlight", but as soon as I'm done, I lable it something else and move on to the next row.  So a "Highlight" in column A could appear in one of 4,000 cells (A1:A4000).  Then the formula needs to highlight all other occurances of the value in that row's B cell. Once I'm finished and it's no longer highlighted, it needs to do the same with the next row I highlight.

Answer (score 0):

With the helper columns idea, I figured it out.  I probably didn't need all the helper columns, but they made it easier.  Column C returns a "TRUE" value if a cell in column B has a match in the same column.  Column D lists all duplicate values in column B.  Column E identifies a value that has duplicates only if there is also a "Highlight" in A.  Column F searches column D (duplicate entries) and returns only those that match column E Entries.  The conditional format scans column F for nonblank cells, and highlights their counterparts in column B.

Column C: =COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,$B1)>1

Column D: =IF($C1=TRUE,$B1,"")

Column E: =IF(AND($A1="Highlight",$C1=TRUE),$D1,"")

Column F: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH($D1,$E$1:$E$10,0)),"",$D1)

Conditional format applied to $B$1:$B$10 is:
=$G1<>""

And that highlights any values in column B that match a highlighted row's cell B.

Thanks, everyone, for your ideas!  You helped me figure this out!